# Why can't I ping from one computer to another using L3 cisco 3550 switch?

Tags: cisco, routing, ping, switch

I have configured my 3550 L3 switch to redirect HTTP traffic to a significant Machine:

This is my scenario ( PCs instead of Routers):

[image]

This is the switch configuration:

```
CAT3550# show running-config 
Building configuration...
.
.
!
interface Vlan1
ip address 10.10.10.1 255.255.255.0 
!
interface Vlan2
ip address 20.20.20.1 255.255.255.0
ip policy route-map pbr
!
interface Vlan3
ip address 30.30.30.1 255.255.255.0
!
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.10.10.2
ip classless
ip http server
!
!
access-list 10 permit 20.20.20.0 0.0.0.255
route-map pbr permit 10
match ip address 10
set ip next-hop 30.30.30.2
!
. 
!
end
```

on the PCs I have put an IP address and a GW:

for example 10.10.10.2 and the gw is:10.10.10.1

My questions is:

Why can't I ping from one computer to another for example (from 20.20.20.4):

> ping 10.10.10.2
>
> return :Request time out.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You seem to be missing the `ip routing` command which enables L3 routing on the switch.

Answer (score 2):

According to the config provided:

> access-list 10 permit 20.20.20.0 0.0.0.255 
> route-map pbr permit 10
>   match ip address 10 
> set ip next-hop 30.30.30.2

Any traffic from the 20.20.20.0/24 subnet traversing the VLAN 2 gateway will be redirected to 30.30.30.2 as a next hop.  This should effectively drop packets destined to 10.10.10.2 when sourced from the 20.20.20.0/24 subnet...  
Unless 30.30.30.2 is in fact configured as a router with a good route to 10.10.10.2, but that wasn't part of the scenario.